# My university is listed on Anabin as H+ but my degree is not listed. Should I worry about this?

Tags: masters, application, germany

I'm planning to do my MSc in Germany and found that in order to apply a master program in Germany, I should check my undergraduate degree is whether acceptable(H+) or not(H-) via Anabin database. The problem is my university is listed on Anabin as H+ but my degree(Abschlussbezeichnung) isn't. The thing is most of the universities listed on Anabin seem to have the same problem. I searched for the BSc-Physics in the US universities but there was only one on the list. Should I worry about this?

Comment: Could someone add an english explanation of Anabin?

Comment: Downvote for unclear question. What are Anabin? H+? H-?Abschlussbezeichnung?

Comment: Anabin is a List of Universities of the world. H+ the institution is considered a university in their country . H- the institution is not considered as an accredited university. H+- a categorization is not possible.

Comment: [Link to Anabin](http://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/institutionen.html), in German only. Click on the "suchen" (search) tab, then on "Alle Länder" to choose a specific country. All the institutions listed with "H+" are accredited universities (according to them, at least).

Answer (score 2):

In the hard end, what some random listing says about your school is irrelevant. **You** will get accepted or not.

The only way to find out how much importance your prospective places for MSc studies place on the listing (or not) of your undergraduate degree is to ask them directly. Attach a *short* description of your undergraduate studies, state the degrees listed in Anabin, and give e.g. your GPA. It might just be that your curriculum is too new to have been included, or has not been presented for evaluation, or has other external certification that might be relevant. That you'll have to ask locally, and add to the above.